# How to write Russian characters in array?

Tags: php

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$arr[] = array('answer_id' => $row['answer_id'], 'answer' => "Привет!");
}
$result->close();
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Instead of Russian characters, answer: null. Browser display:

```
[Object]  
0: Object  
answer: null  
answer_id: "1010002"  
__proto__: Object  
length: 1  
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: Post actual output, please. What you've posted is not valid json.

Comment: Why? This is JSON array.

Comment: The browser displays: [{"answer_id":"1010002","answer":null}]

Comment: Is answer hardcoded or comes from db?

Comment: answer hardcoded. answer_id comes from db.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code editor to make sure your php file is in UTF-8.

Comment: I dont think it can convert `Привет!` to `null`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I converted to utf-8. Helped.